# JSP template implementation (Composite View Pattern)

Tags: java, jsp, templates

What is the best way to implement the Composite View Pattern for a Java website?

My idea was to take one jsp and include multiple pages like:

```
<h1>Layout Start</h1>
<%
Values values = DataHandler.getValues(request);
LayoutHelper layout = values.getLayout();
out.println("Layout.getContent(): " + layout.getContent());
%>

<jsp:include page="<%= layout.getContent() %>" flush="false" />

<h1>Layout End</h1>
```

But then all my small jsp files in the WEB-INF directory are still available to the user. How can I deny access to all .jsp files except for the one template.

After that I need a filter or Servlet to insert the paths in the Values object.

**Update**
I don't mean that the WEB-INF is accessible from the file system (Or Webserver) but from the web app through the controller with my current layout `layout.getcontent()` maps to an URL parameter/user input.

What are the common used frameworks to handle the Composite View Pattern??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Pro Java EE and Spring Patterns](http://books.google.com.pe/books?id=Libjk0Oa87QC&pg=PA118&lpg=PA118&dq=composite%20view%20pattern%20framework&source=bl&ots=04HfgS4Dy-&sig=_vOL1IiLstQ13J1R8zOUeAjKAF4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=wf6CT5KTFoyi8gTAyczIBw&sqi=2&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=composite%20view%20pattern%20framework&f=false) mentions  two popular framework that supports the Composite View pattern:

- [Apache Tiles](http://tiles.apache.org/)
- [SiteMesh](http://www.sitemesh.org/getting-started.html)

Personally I used Tiles and It worked like a charm integrated with Struts and Spring. SiteMesh also relies on the Decorator Pattern. In Tiles Web Site there's a [nice comparison](http://tiles.apache.org/tutorial/pattern.html) between the benefits of both patterns.

Answer (score 4):

Any file that's in `WEB-INF` is not directly accessible by the user.  I typically put all my JSPs in `WEB-INF/jsp`, and then only the controller servlet (or other JSP pages) can access them.

Comment: What he said. This is in fact what a lot of framework do/encourage.

Answer (score 2):

Apache Tiles is working on this concept.

http://tiles.apache.org/framework/tutorial/pattern.html

It is worth looking into this.