# How to execute JSP in desktop application?

Tags: java, jsp, desktop-application

JSP can be regarded as nice template and/or preprocessor engine. I would like to generate some XML files by program with it.

What is the simplest way to accomplish this?

Comment: Mb you consider using another template engine. For example http://www.stringtemplate.org/ . JSP is actually converted to java servlet which requires container and such. Lots of overhead don't you think so?

Comment: there is a jsp option: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18878079/217324

Comment: @YuryTarabanko what is JSTP

Comment: 'JSTP is basically a subset of JSP, and a build time translator of it.' from the answer @NathanHughes linked to.

Answer (score 0):

tomcat has a jsp compiler, which is wrapped up quite nicely in an ant task that you can just call: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/jasper/JspC.html